# JTable Won't show data after inserted

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

So I'm kind of new in java and netbeans, but I wrote a code to load some data from the database and show it in a JTable, When I did it a couple of days ago it worked just fine and showed everything yet when I opened it today it wont show anything, I really don't know why and I checked almost everything.
Here is the code:

NOTE: I uploaded all of the code in case it was required, but you should probably check the method of the button btnLoad which performs the insertion.

```
package cinemaohadid;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class AllMovies extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public AllMovies() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tblAllMovies = new javax.swing.JTable();
    btnLoad = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Watch All Movies");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 325, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    tblAllMovies.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "ID", "Title", "Genre", "Show Time"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    tblAllMovies.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 0));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblAllMovies);
    tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    if (tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
        tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(20);
        tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(20);
        tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
        tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(60);
        tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        tblAllMovies.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(120);
    }

    btnLoad.setText("Load");
    btnLoad.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnLoadActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 488, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btnLoad)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(btnLoad)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnLoadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String user = "aa";
    String pass = "aa";
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Results";

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblAllMovies.getModel();
    Connection con;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Movies";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
        int rowcount=-1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            rowcount++;
            int movieID = rs.getInt("MOVIEID");
            String movieName = rs.getString("MOVIENAME");
            Timestamp movieTime = rs.getTimestamp("MOVIETIME");
            String movieGenre = rs.getString("MOVIEGENRE");
            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{movieID,movieName ,movieGenre ,movieTime});
        }
        dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
    //btnLoad.setVisible(false);

}                                       

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AllMovies.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AllMovies.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AllMovies.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AllMovies.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>








    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AllMovies().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnLoad;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable tblAllMovies;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: "tried all options" removed from title. It's down-vote bait.

Comment: Please elaborate. You state "it won't show anything", does the GUI show at all? What exactly is happening now?

Comment: Code looks reasonable except you should never invoke `dtm.fireTableDataChanged()`. It is the job of the model to invoke the appropriate fireXXX method as each row is added to the model. Add a `System.out.println(...)` to make sure you actually have data in the `ResultSet`.

Comment: The GUI shows the headers, but it displays an empty table, as if I did nothing with my button click

Comment: `but it displays an empty table` - and did you add a System.out.println(...) to your code to verify the results of the SQL query. If the ResultSet is empty the problem is with your SQL. If it is not empty, then your code doesn't have a reference to the "tblAllMovies" table this is visible on the GUI.

Comment: Used breakpoints to follow the whole porcedure, the ResultSet gets it all and the table model shows as if it had all of the rows inside it, it just wont show on the screen, I already stated it but it worked just like that a couple of days ago and I dont remember messing with anything, so it's really wierd to me

Comment: @AmirYadid, did some more testing and found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could you edit the code or give me an example of what to replace in my code

```
//dtm.addRow(new Object[]{movieID,movieName ,movieGenre ,movieTime});
Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
row.addElement(movieID);
row.addElement(movieName);
row.addElement(movieGenre);
row.addElement(movieTime);
```

My comment about the indexes was for the example moarCoffee posted. A Vector just adds the objects sequentially so you don't need to worry about hardcoding an index.

Also, this suggestion will not solve your problem.

Edit:

The point of posting a SSCCE is to simplify the code. We don't have access to your database so we can't run the code. So your SSCCE should be code that demonstrates the problem. This is done by removing the SQL logic and instead using:

```
private void btnLoadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblAllMovies.getModel();
    dtm.addRow( new Object[]{new Integer(1), "movieName1" , "movieGenre1", "movieTime1"} );
    dtm.addRow( new Object[]{new Integer(2), "movieName2" , "movieGenre2", "movieTime2"} );
    dtm.addRow( new Object[]{new Integer(3), "movieName3" , "movieGenre3", "movieTime3"} );
    dtm.addRow( new Object[]{new Integer(4), "movieName4" , "movieGenre4", "movieTime4"} );
}
```

Indeed the problem still exists so this verifies the problem is NOT with the SQL.

Next I took a look at all the junk code generated by the IDE to do the layout. Sure enough I found the following line:

```
tblAllMovies.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 0));
```

When I commented out that line it worked. Don't use the `setPreferredSize()` method when using Swing.

Another recommendation is to NOT use an IDE to generate layout code. The code is impossible to understand and will not be portable if you ever move to another IDE.

The layout could have been done in a couple of lines of code:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Box east = Box.CreateVerticalBox();
east.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
east.add(button);
frame.add(east, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Instead that much simpler and easier to understand than all the code generated by the IDE. You can easily customize the above to add a few Borders to make is look exactly the way to want in another couple of lines of code.

Comment: It solved the problem, now I recall that it said 400,0 by default and I changed that, and then when I wanted to return it to the previous value I typed it instead of resetting to default, which set its height to 0, a foolish mistake by me, thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting in `pack();` in the `btnLoadActionPerformed` method after you close the result set? It seems like you're telling the table that its values have changed but are not updating the graphical elements.

For what it's worth, this is how I would have done it. First make a new class that extends the default table model:

```
class MovieTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[] {false, false, false, false};

    public MovieTableModel() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[columnIndex]; // or just return false if it's always going to be false
    }
}
```

And then change `btnLoadActionPerformed` to

```
private void btnLoadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String user = "aa";
    String pass = "aa";
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Results";

    Connection con;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Movies";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        MovieTableModel mtm = new MovieTableModel();
        mtm.addColumn("ID");
        mtm.addColumn("Title");
        mtm.addColumn("Genre");
        mtm.addColumn("Show Time");

        Vector<Object> row;

        while (rs.next()) {
            row = new Vector<Object>();

            row.add(rs.getInt("MOVIEID"));
            row.add(rs.getString("MOVIENAME"));
            row.add(rs.getTimestamp("MOVIETIME"));
            row.add(rs.getString("MOVIEGENRE"));

            mtm.addRow(row);
        }

        tblAllMovies = new JTable(mtm);
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
        pack();
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

==EDIT==

Updated method to use vectors instead of arrays to populate the table.

Comment: Don't use a 2D Array for the data. Instead create a Vector for each row of data and add the `Vector` to the `DefaultTableModel` using the `addRow()` method. If you use the Array, the DefaultTableModel will just convert the Array to a Vector anyway so you are just wasting memory by allocating the full size of the Array. A Vector is easier anyway since you don't have to worry about the indexes.

Comment: Excuse me but I dont know much about how to define this vector, could you edit the code or give me an example of what to replace in my code (since you said in vectors there are no indexes I dont know how to access the fields

Comment: @AmirYadid I updated the code to use vectors. Vectors do have indexes, it's just that you can forgo setting values with an index (like in an array) by using the `add` method. Check out the [Vector documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).